# Create product collection in PHTML with filter based on Category ID

Tags: magento2

We want to get a Product Collection based on a filter with the category ID.

In our case, we have the desired Category with ID 43.

Our Call looks like this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$productcollection = $productCollection->create()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->load();
```

I tried it with `->addFieldToFilter('category', '43')`, but it didn't worked for me. I also tried it with the following: `->addCategoriesFilter(['eq' => 43])`, but that also don't work. With the last statement my Query looks like this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$productcollection = $productCollection->create()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addCategoriesFilter(['eq' => 43])
                    ->load();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

You should never use the ObjectManager.

You can put this in the Block, and call the function  `getProductCollection()` in the phtml :

```
namespace Company\Module\Block;

class CustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    protected $_categoryFactory;    

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    ) {
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $categoryId = '43';
        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you advise here to modify a core file? If not, please advise how "to put this in the block". Thank you.

Comment: no you should never edit a core file. This guide https://mageinferno.com/blog/how-create-template-block-magento-2 will help you to create a custom block for the phtml

Comment: Thanks for that link. Which class should be extended when using your code? I understand that I need to write an extra module for that, hence the question. I can only inject a custom function into the block when I need which block is needed to be extended here. I hope you can follow my question.

Comment: The custom block should extend the class `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`

Comment: Check the edited answer